# Freemarker integration with SparkJava produces unexpected unicode string output

Tags: java, templates, render, freemarker, spark-java

I am building an application in SparkJava with freemarker integration.

I am trying to render a freemarker template (actually containing no vars):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In my controller I have the following configuration:

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_26);
final ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
configuration.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(contextClassLoader.getResource("www/public").toURI()));
configuration.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
configuration.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
configuration.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
return new FreeMarkerEngine(configuration).render(new ModelAndView(Collections.singletonMap("",""), "index.ftl"));
```

But the result output in the browser is the following:

> "\u003c!DOCTYPE html\u003e\n\u003chtml
>   lang\u003d\"en\"\u003e\n\u003chead\u003e\n \u003cmeta
>   charset\u003d\"UTF-8\"\u003e\n
>   \u003ctitle\u003eTitle\u003c/title\u003e\n\u003c/head\u003e\n\u003cbody\u003e\n\u003cp\u003ehello\u003c/p\u003e\n\u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"

What am I doing wrong and how can I render the page correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is trivial: in such situation the route statement looked like the following:

```
get("/hello", aMethodToRenderPage, gson::toJson);
```

Where the call `toJson` refers to the following method

```
@Override
public String render(Object model) {
    return gson.toJson(model);
}
```

defined in a ResponseTransformer. That transforms the response into JSON String by turning chars into unicode representation. 
**To get the desired output** (HTML with filled in vars), **remove** such call, so that it looks like:

```
get("/hello", aMethodToRenderPage);
```